# With C#, How do I get "Application.StartupPath" to return mapped drive path and not UNC path?

Tags: c#, uac

When my application is using an app.manifest, and the line below is set as shown

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

the code

```
textBox1.Text = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "setupws.exe");
```

returns `"\\server\myApp\setupws.exe"`

If I change the `requestedExecutionLevel` to `"asInvoker"`, or remove the `app.manifest` altogether, it returns `"F:\myApp\setupws.exe"`. Which is what I need.

Is there a way to get `Application.StartupPath` to behave the way I want and *still* use `requireAdministrator`?

Comment: Why don't you just translate the UNC path to a mapped drive path?

Comment: Drive mappings are relative to the *user*, UNC paths are relative to *no one*.

Comment: Might be that the mapped drive does not exist when you are elevated. I've observed similar things in the past where after elevation all mapped drives were gone. So maybe UNC is the only thing actually available for Windows to give you?

Comment: @ David - I can find plenty of articles on how to translate mapped to UNC but nothing for UNC to mapped.

Comment: @Zarat - Thought of that but EnableLinkedConnections is present in the registry. Making the mapped drive available to any level of access.

Comment: It's a good point about elevating and drive mappings. Modern Windows seems to handle it better, but certainly it was an issue in the early days of UAC.

Comment: What about this: http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/get-local-path-from-unc-path/  Anyway, I wonder why you need to do this at all. What's so bad about the UNC path?

Comment: *Why* is having the UNC path an issue? 0.0000005 seconds after launching your program, the user may un-map the drive they launched it from.

Comment: Or to put it another way, *why* do you (think) you need the mapped path?

Comment: I wish UNC wasn't a problem. But My "real" code starts an old Borland process that doesnt play well with UNC's

Comment: Then your code needs to map a path itself and then launch the borland code - you can't trust users to maintain mappings.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan IIRC, that approach (using system management api) requires a certain level of access rights on the remote server (i.e., unc host) - might not be an issue in this case, but "for the record"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any way to change the response you're getting, but you can always try to remap back the UNC to local - to do this, you'll need to call out to the underlying Win32 calls (C dll calls) using "Platform Invoke", or "PInvoke"; the syntax for referring to a win32 call looks a bit like:

```
[DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool WNetGetConnection(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string localName, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder remoteName, 
    ref int length);
```

(What this is doing is mapping the unmanaged call/types to their managed equivalents, as well as telling the compiler "Hey, there's code outside of this stuff that I'm going to call")

`WNetGetConnection` is a fairly ho-hum Windows function: give it a drive letter, and you'll get back a UNC path, if it's mapped to one. We'll cycle through the "known drive letters", feeding each one in turn to this call, and if we get any partial matches with the returned UNC name and the path we're trying to "reverse map", we'll replace the UNC part of the path with the corresponding drive letter and we're done:

```
public string GetLocalPathForUnc(string uncName)
{
    var mapped = Environment.GetLogicalDrives().Select(drive => 
    {
        drive = drive.Substring(0,2);
        var buffer = new StringBuilder(0xff);
        int length = 0xff;
        WNetGetConnection(drive, buffer, ref length);
        return new {Drive = drive, Unc = buffer.ToString()};
    });
    var match = mapped
            .Where(ob => 
                 !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ob.Drive) && 
                 !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ob.Unc))
        .FirstOrDefault(ob => uncName.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith(ob.Unc.ToLowerInvariant()));
    return uncName.Replace(match.Unc, match.Drive);
}
```

Comment: Well that does the job. But my poor beginners mind has NO idea what its doing. I can live with that!

Comment: Hah - no worries, lemme add some explanatory text. :)

Comment: @JimDel There, have a read on that - hopefully it explains a bit better.